# what happens if Amaterasu is cast on another Amaterasu?

Tags: naruto

Can the inextinguishable flames of Amaterasu burn the Amaterasu cast by another user? Will they both cease to exist or burn forever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To first answer this question; we must first look into "What can turn off Amaterasu"

- Amaterasu lasts 7 days and 7 nights
- Amaterasu can be turned off by the user's will
- Amaterasu is turned off when the material projected onto it has been burned

With that being said, Amaterasu 2 will not "burn out" Amaterasu 1, they will simply burn for 7 days and 7 nights before they will both cease to exist.
Here you can [read more](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amaterasu) about Amaterasu